# Delete function in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm writing a code for a simple commenting list, and I can't figure out how to delete an item from my "Commenting list" I have added a delete button but I am missing the function that enables it to actually do something. This is the code:

```
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';



export default class CommentList extends React.Component {
    
 
    static propTypes = {
        items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
    };
    
      
       
    renderItem = (item, index) => (
        <View key={index} style={styles.comment}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
            <Button
            //onPress={}
            title="Delete"
            color="black"
            accessibilityLabel="Delete comments"
            />
        </View>
        );
        render() {
            const { items } = this.props;
            return <ScrollView>{items.map(this.renderItem) }  
            
            </ScrollView>;
        }



}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    comment: {
        marginLeft: 20,
        paddingVertical: 20,
        paddingRight: 20,
        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        borderBottomColor: 'black',
    },

});
```

Here I have added the code of the parent component. This will hopefully provide some more context for my question.

```
import { SafeAreaView, ViewPropTypes, Button} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

import NavigationBar from '../components/NavigationBar';
import CommentList from '../components/CommentList';
import CommentInput from '../components/CommentInput';



export default function Comments({
    style,
    onSubmitComment,
    onClose,
    comments,


}) {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style = {style}>
            <NavigationBar
                title="Comments"
                leftText= 'Close'
                onPressLeftText= {onClose}
                />

                <CommentInput placeholder = "Leave a Comment" onSubmit={onSubmitComment} />
                <CommentList items ={comments} />

        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

Comments.propTypes = {
    style: ViewPropTypes.style,
    comments: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
    onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onSubmitComment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 };

 Comments.defaultProps = {
    style: null,
 };
```

Finally I have added where the code showing where the comments are created.

```
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

export default class CommentInput extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    placeholder: '',
  };

  state = {
    text: '',
  };

  handleChangeText = text => {
    this.setState({ text });
  };

  handleSubmitEditing = () => {
    const { onSubmit } = this.props;
    const { text } = this.state;


    if (!text) return;

    onSubmit(text);
    this.setState({ text: '' });
  };

  render() {
    const { placeholder } = this.props;
    const { text } = this.state;


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={text}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
          onSubmitEditing={this.handleSubmitEditing}
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderBottomColor: 'white',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    height: 200,
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: you will need to delete the item from the `items` array, which you pass as a prop. If you want to keep class-based components you will need to pass the delete function from the parent down to the child as well.

Comment: Thank you. Can you maybe help explain what the function could look like and where to place it? I wouldn't ask if I hadn't just spent a long time trying to figure it out my self. Without any success I might add.

Comment: Can you provide a repo or the code of your parent component as well?

Comment: Yes of course, thank you.

Comment: Do you have react experience as a WEB app, because it seems that you are trying react-native (RN) but without prior react knowledge? I am asking because I am just curious, how something like this happens. I thought RN is mostly used by react developers who want to get their foot into mobile apps.

Comment: I understand why you are curious. I have no prior experience with react. We were taught react native as an introduction class to app development and this project is me trying to better understand it.

Comment: Hmm, okay I would recommend that you start with common react. It is easier to learn and you will get much more help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8&t

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely take a look at commen react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu should update The comment List from where you save it into your state. After looking at your repo, this would be in your App root

You need to adjust

```
// add this function to your app

  deleteCommentFromSource = (id, item) => {
    const { selectedItemId, commentsForItem } = this.state;
    // here we need to delete the comment from the state
    const updatedCommentList = commentsForItem[selectedItemId].filter((comment) => {
      if ( comment !== item) {
        return comment;
      }
    });
    console.log(updatedCommentList);
    this.setState({ commentsForItem: updatedCommentList })
  };
```

```
// in the render method the new function needs to be passed
          <Comments
            deleteCommentFromSource={this.deleteCommentFromSource}
            style={styles.comments}
            comments={commentsForItem[selectedItemId] || []}
            onClose={this.closeCommentScreen}
            onSubmitComment={this.onSubmitComment}
          />
```

Then I would recommend creating for every comment an own Component, after you properly passed the function down to the component, you can call the method on your app component to update the comments.

The comment component looks like this

```
export default function Comment({
    title,
    color,
    item,
    id,
    deleteCommentFromSource,
}) {
    function deleteCommentHandler(){
        console.log("delete comment");
        console.log("text",item);
        console.log(id);
        deleteCommentFromSource(id, item) // usually you would pass in comment id 
    }

    return (
        <View key={id} style={styles.comment}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
            <Button
            onPress={deleteCommentHandler}
            title={title}
            color={color}
            accessibilityLabel="Delete comments"
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

**IMPORTANT**

I notice that you currently use the index as a key. Your comments should not simply hold an array of comments, rather an array of comment objects.

Example:

```
comments = [
{id: 1, text: "some comment"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you again, I'm ashamed that I have to ask this but I don't quite know what code to move. At least I cannot get it to work. I have added the code where the comment is created to my question.

Comment: Don't be ashamed, coding is hard and I am certainly not the best teacher :D Can you include error messages? It also would help a lot if you share a github repo with me for the project, then I can fix it there.

Comment: Thank you so much again again, I really appreciate that you help me :) I have created a GitHub repo for the project now, and here is the link: https://github.com/eightply/thingImDoing_2.git

Comment: I made pull request.

Comment: Thank you so much, you really helped me out a lot!

Comment: Cool, I will adjust my answer. I would appreciate it if you accept it.

Comment: Be careful currently All comments with the same text will be deleted. Your need to make some minor adjustments to the filter function.

Comment: Ok I will look more into the filter function. Thank you again for helping me :)